# Prestashop 1.5.3.1. free shipping

Tags: prestashop

How to set a different free shipping border for each of my carriers? For exmple
carrier 1: free shipping starts @ $100
carrier 1: free shipping starts @ $200

Answer (score 2):

This is easy. Go to Back Office -> Shipping -> Price Ranges. You can add different ranges for each individual carrier. After creating all the ranges, click Shipping again. Scroll to bottom and you will see "Fees by carrier, geographical zone, and ranges". Voila!

Comment: The only issue with this and PrestaShop, is if you offer free-shipping on for example a 0 lbs item, you add another item it will allow shipping this free item next day and charge you a grip.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the module to specific courier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that is not how I did it. I used the override to add a second free shipping price, then in cart.php i've connected it to a specific carrier(id)
override:

```
'PS_SHIPPING_FREE_PRICE' => array(
                        'title' => $this->l('Free shipping starts at'),
                        'suffix' => $this->context->currency->getSign(),
                        'cast' => 'floatval',
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'validation' => 'isPrice'),
                    'PS_SHIPPING_FREE_PRICE2' => array(
                        'title' => $this->l('Free shipping2 starts at'),
                        'suffix' => $this->context->currency->getSign(),
                        'cast' => 'floatval',
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'validation' => 'isPrice'),
cart.php:
```

$configuration = Configuration::getMultiple(array(
            'PS_SHIPPING_FREE_PRICE',
            'PS_SHIPPING_FREE_PRICE2',
            'PS_SHIPPING_HANDLING',
            'PS_SHIPPING_METHOD',
            'PS_SHIPPING_FREE_WEIGHT'
        ));

```
    // Free fees
        $free_fees_price = 0;
        if (isset($configuration['PS_SHIPPING_FREE_PRICE']))
            if($id_carrier==27)  
            $free_fees_price = Tools::convertPrice((float)$configuration['PS_SHIPPING_FREE_PRICE2'], Currency::getCurrencyInstance((int)$this->id_currency));
        else
            $free_fees_price = Tools::convertPrice((float)$configuration['PS_SHIPPING_FREE_PRICE'], Currency::getCurrencyInstance((int)$this->id_currency));
```

this is working fine for me, but every time you update your carrier, it gets new id, so you must update and cart.php
Also its better to use the override for cart.php, but i just could not do it